# Can Azure SQL Server on VM be the production database?

Tags: sql-server, azure

I am trying to figure out the difference between Azure SQL Server on VM and the Azure SQL Server database. I know one is IaaS and another is a PaaS Service. But there is one thing I still don't understand that which one could use for Dev/test and which one could use for production? or both of them have such capabilities?

As my understanding. The Azure SQL Server on VM is only for the Dev/test, if you need to go production, need to use Azure SQL server database. So I need to transfer my data from VM to the SQL Database. Am I correct?

Comment: _The Azure SQLserver on VM is only for the Dev/test, if you need to go production, need to use Azure SQL server database_ No. Do whatever you like. There's no rules about what type has to be what environment. We have dev and prod in on-premise, in IaaS and in PaaS. Do you mean this from a licencing perspective?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Thanks for your quick reply! I am not mean the licencing perspective. Just can't find the Prod function on the VM Sql Server. How could I find the Dev and Prod functions on the SQLserver on VM?

Comment: There is no such thing as “dev and prod function”. What makes you think you can’t use SQL Azure for Dev purposes?

Comment: I just think SQL server on VM does not have Prod as sql server is in the VM not on the cloud. Am I right..?

Comment: On the cloud just means it is in some one else's datacenter (in the case of Azure, it is Microsoft). You can still host Production Servers on Azure VMs. To be specific, Microsoft does not care if you host dev or prod on the VM , it still charges you the same.

Comment: Thanks@SQLApostle! I think I am totally get what you mean. :)

Comment: "does not have Prod" does not make sense. You should do some reading about environments. Environments (Dev/Test) are completely unrelated to platform (on-prem, IaaS, PaaS). But Environments should be on the same _version_ of the platform

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid  I think I just have confused about Environments on the SQL platform. Will do some research. Anyway, thanks so much for your comments!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Nick McDermaid mentions, there isn't anything that states SQLServer on VM is only for Dev and Test.

here is the info on this space from Microsoft- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-paas-vs-sql-server-iaas

Production is always hard. Using a Managed Service makes life easier at the job of maintaining and operating it is with the service provider instead of you performing the role.

I would always choose a Managed Service (in this case Azure SQL PaaS Service) over the IaaS version for both Dev and Production workloads.

Comment: Thanks so much for your explanation! Probably the Managed Service is a good choice for me.

Answer (score 3):

"Production Environment" is a term for a system that needs to be stable, reliable, fast and has all changes managed to it, is supported by a team. If Production has bugs or performance issues, they are known about and in the process of being fixed.

"Development Environment" is the environment that you use to make your changes (which inevitably have bugs, and which is unstable)

There is no relationship between environment type and IaaS, PaaS, on-premise, managed instances of SQL Server.

In fact it's a *bad* idea to have DEV is on IaaS and Prod on PaaS, because these are different *versions* of SQL Server. Your environments should be as identical as possible including the version.

Comment: This is the better answer, IMO. Comparing development environments (Dev, Stage, Test, Prod) to IaaS, PaaS is like comparing apples to carburetors. They're not even in the same *category*.

Answer (score 0):

As with all SQL Design questions , "It depends".

```
Does your application have multiple databases which have cross database queries ? 
Does it rely on linked servers ?
Do you use service broker in your application ?
Do you use SQL agent jobs a lot ?
etc ...
```

If yes, Azure SQL database might not be the right one for you.

Also, you should be doing **dev / test / UAT / prod** on **similar / equal / exactly same** environments. Doing dev / test on an Azure VM and then moving to prod in Azure SQL database will cause a lot of problems as the two are not exactly the same ( Azure SQL database as a PaaS offering is very limited in Server level features as compared to a IaaS offering)

I would suggest reading through the feature comparison here for more understanding of which one to use depending on your requirements of features

```
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/40295.sql-server-features-and-basic-comparison-at-iaas-vs-paas-vs-on-premise.aspx
```