# Which one is Azure SQL Server for production?

Tags: sql-server, azure, production

[image]

As the graph shows above. Which type of sql server edition is for the production? I know the "Developer" version is for the development. Also I already got the Azure VM and have the "Developer SQL Server" on my VM, how can I install the production SQL Server in my VM? Is this free?

My purpose is to make a production SQL Server database. Is there two options for me? One is install a production SQL Server in my VM, another is to create a new Azure SQL database. Which one would be the best way to do this?

Comment: If you have to ask this question, then I would suggest getting Azure SQL. You can't just install any version of SQL Server without paying for it.

Comment: All except Developer may be used for production. The VM images have SQL Server preinstalled. You can either bring your own license (BYOL) or pay per usage, which includes the SQL license costs. See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2017) for edition differences and [licensing/pricing guidance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sql/virtual-machines-windows-sql-server-pricing-guidance). Also consider, Azure SQL Database as @DavidG suggested.

Comment: Here is some background everyone: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52322587/can-azure-sql-server-on-vm-be-the-production-database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As the graph shows above. Which type of sql server edition is for the
>   Production? I know the "Developer" version is for the development.
>   Also I already got the Azure VM and have the "Developer SQl server" on
>   my VM, how can I install the production sql server on my VM? Is this
>   free?

- Developer is not *licenced* for production - you aren't allowed to use it for production purposes.
- Express is licenced for production but if your database gets bigger that 10Gb then it is unsuitable for your use

> My purpose is to make a production sql server database. Is there two
>   options for me? One is install a production sql server on my VM,
>   another is to create a new Azure SQL database. Which one would be the
>   best way to do this?

"Best" doesn't mean anything. What are your constraints? Are you creating a brand new database? What tools will be connecting to and using the database? Does it need to be accessible from the internet?

If this is a brand new application / database, and you have limited capability for maintaining a VM then I definitely recommend using SQL Azure instead of a VM

Most importantly, and based on you other question, make sure you understand the term "Production"

[Can Azure SQL Server on VM be the production database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52322587/can-azure-sql-server-on-vm-be-the-production-database)

For example, you usually don't provision a 'production' environment without also provisioning at least a dev environment.

It would also help to give us some background on "My purpose is to make a production sql server database". It sounds like this is a request someone has given you but maybe you don't fully understand the term 'production'

Comment: Thanks so much for your explanation Nick! Yes, my boss just give one project to do. I am quite new in this area so not understand the "Production" and "Dev/Test"..

Comment: I suggest you read the Wikipedia article on it to understand a bit better: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deployment_environment

Answer (score 0):

None of them are sql azure. They are all sql server on premise on a virtual machine on azure.
If you want to add a sql server azure, you go on your main azure portal page, then on the left panel at the top "create a resource", then chose "SQL Database" on the popular column. Then follow instructions.

If you want as less pain as possible, clearly choose sql azure instead of a sql server on premise on a virtual server on azure. It is by very far the only reasonable choice if you work on azure: cheap, strong, backup automatically done, disaster recovery extremely easily applicable without any prior setup, extremely easy to up size its capacity in case of overload, perfectly secured without any prior setup either.

The only problem of this is the security: it can be accessed only by recognized IP addresses that you mention on the azure portal. So typically, you mention the IP address of you development computer. If your website is on your azure subscription as well, you don't need to worry, it will go through the azure firewall with no setup.

If you reeeeeeally want to use a sql server on premise, well, don't use the developer edition. If you want to avoid performance and load issues, don't use express. The entreprise is very complete, but not useful in most of cases for simple application (like web applications).

If you want most of features, go for the Standard edition, if you want to keep focused on the database engine for your web application, go for the Web edition.

Finaly, if you wanna have a licence free edition on a virtual server, the express is free of charges, but not powerful and extremely limited. The developer edition is free of charges as well and contains every possible and impossible features of sql server. The only pb of this edition is that you are not allowed to use it in production. Only for tests and developments.

Comment: Thanks so much for your explanation! much clearer :)

Answer (score 0):

As you are already having Azure VM with Developer edition installed you can go for either of the below options.

- **If you are comfortable to manage the Azure VM yourself, go for IAAS(Infrastructure as a Service) approach:** Install SQL Server Standard Edition or SQL Server Enterprise Edition (based on your application needs). [Read the capability difference between them](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2016?view=sql-server-2017). If SQL Server Express edition would be suitable for your needs, then install the same. It does have limited features and many constraints. See the scalability support for different editions in the same link above.
- **If you want to offload the database server management, go for PAAS(Platform as a Service) approach**: Create a Azure SQL database and point your application to it. Azure SQL database is more like SQL Server Enterprise Edition with some limitations like CLR not being supported. [Read Azure SQL database differences with SQL Server editions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-features)